# PHP Redirect a file from another server to end user

Tags: php, redirect, curl, get, download

I want to be able to allow user to enter in variable URL which file they would like to download from remote server URL e.g  /download.php?url=fvr_anim_foxintro_V4_01.jpg

```
<?php 
$url = $_GET['url'];
header("Location: http://fvr.homestead.com/files/animation/" . $url);
?>
```

The above is purely an example I grabbed from google images. The problem is I do not want the end user to be allowed to see where the file is originally coming from so it would need to get the file download to the server and the server passes it along to the end user. Is there a method of doing this?

I find many examples for files hosted on the server but no examples for serving files hosted on a remote server. In other words I would be passing them along.  The files would be quite large (up to 100MB)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be sure to take the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cURL for this:

```
<?php
$url = "http://share.meebo.com/content/katy_perry/wallpapers/3.jpg";

$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 0;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

// Getting binary data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);

$image = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// output to browser
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $image;
?>
```

Source: http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/120308-solved-curl-get-image/

Of course, this example is just for an image (as you've suggested) but you can use cURL for all kinds of remote data retrieval via HTTP GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc. Search around the web for "php curl" and you'll find an endless supply of information.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution would be to use [PHP's cURL Library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), but if you're using shared hosting keep in mind this library may be disabled.

Assuming you can use cURL, you simply echo the `Content-type` header with the appropriate MIME Type and echo the results from `curl_exec()`.

To get a basic idea of how to use the cURL library, look at the example under the [`curl_init()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php) function.